# My cubes have disappeared and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, opengl, webgl

I'm trying to create a program consisting of two cubes, one with colors, the other with a colored texture. These cubes move and rotate depending on input from the keyboard as follows:

u - up, d - down, l - left, r - right, i - in, o - out, g - grow, s - shrink

x/y/z - spin along cube's x/y/z-axis

shift + x/y/z - same as above but in opposite direction and the button switches between the cubes.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;
uniform vec4 posiz;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remember: these matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
                    0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
                    0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
                    0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                    s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
                    s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    // position matrix
    mat4 posMat = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
                        posiz[0], posiz[1], posiz[2],  1.0 );

    // size matrix
    mat4 sizMat = mat4( posiz[3],  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  posiz[3],  0.0,  0.0,
                        0.0,  0.0,  posiz[3],  0.0,
                        0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = sizMat * posMat * rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="vertex-shader-texture" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
attribute  vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main() 
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader-texture" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor * texture2D( texture, fTexCoord );
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myCubes.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>

<br/>

<input type = "button" value = "First" id = "switchButton" ></input>

<img id = "texImage" src = "diagram.png" hidden></img>
</body>
</html>
```

files webgl-utils.js, initShaders.js, and MV.js can be found here:

http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/

And here is the accompanying javascript file:

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];

var texture; // second cube texture

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis1 = 0;
var axis2 = 0;

var rot1 = 1.0; // rate of rotation
var rot2 = 1.0;

var theta1 = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
var theta2 = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

// cube position along x, y, and z axis and size
var posiz1 = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ];
var posiz2 = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ];

// used to send info back to html, I think
var thetaLoc;
var posLoc;

var firstCube = true;

// globals
var program;
var programTexture;
var iBuffer;
var cBuffer;
var vColor;
var vBuffer;
var vPosition;
var cBufferTexture;
var vColorTexture;
var vBufferTexture;
var vPositionTexture;
var tBuffer;
var vTexCoord;
var image;

    var vertices = [
        vec3( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
        vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
    ];

// indices of the 12 triangles that comprise the cube
var indices = [
    1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 6, 2,
    3, 0, 4, 4, 7, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 6,
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 5
];

// texture coordinates
var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

function configureTexture( image )
{
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(programTexture, "texture"), 0);
}

function quad(a, b, c, d)
{
     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]); 
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[3]);   
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    //event listeners for buttons
    document.getElementById( "switchButton" ).onclick = function ()
    {
        firstCube = !firstCube; // switch between cubes

        if (firstCube) document.getElementById("switchButton").value = "First";
        else document.getElementById("switchButton").value = "Second";
    };

    window.onkeydown = function(event)
    {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

        if (firstCube)
        {
            if (key == 'R') posiz1[0] += .1;
            else if (key == 'L') posiz1[0] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'U') posiz1[1] += .1;
            else if (key == 'D') posiz1[1] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'I') posiz1[2] += .1;
            else if (key == 'O') posiz1[2] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'G') posiz1[3] += .1;
            else if (key == 'S') posiz1[3] -= .1;

            if (event.shiftKey == 0 && (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z'))
                rot1 = -1.0;
            else if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z')
                rot1 = 1.0;

            if (key == 'X') axis1 = xAxis;
            if (key == 'Y') axis1 = yAxis;
            if (key == 'Z') axis1 = zAxis;
        }
        else
        {
            if (key == 'R') posiz2[0] += .1;
            else if (key == 'L') posiz2[0] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'U') posiz2[1] += .1;
            else if (key == 'D') posiz2[1] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'I') posiz2[2] += .1;
            else if (key == 'O') posiz2[2] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'G') posiz2[3] += .1;
            else if (key == 'S') posiz2[3] -= .1;

            if (event.shiftKey == 0 && (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z'))
                rot2 = -1.0;
            else if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z')
                rot2 = 1.0;

            if (key == 'X') axis2 = xAxis;
            if (key == 'Y') axis2 = yAxis;
            if (key == 'Z') axis2 = zAxis;
        }
    };

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    programTexture = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader-texture", "fragment-shader-texture" );

    gl.useProgram( program );
    colorCube();

    // array element buffer    
    iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // color array attribute buffer
    cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    // vertex array attribute buffer
    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    // get started on textured cube
    gl.useProgram( programTexture);

    cBufferTexture = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBufferTexture );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vColorTexture = gl.getAttribLocation( programTexture, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColorTexture, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColorTexture );

    vBufferTexture = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBufferTexture );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vPositionTexture = gl.getAttribLocation( programTexture, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPositionTexture, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPositionTexture );

    tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation( programTexture, "vTexCoord" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vTexCoord );

    image = document.getElementById("texImage");

    configureTexture( image );

    render();
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(program);

    // connect location to variable in html
    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");
    posizLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "posiz");

    // handle rendering of first cube
    theta1[axis1] += rot1;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta1);
    gl.uniform4fv(posizLoc, posiz1);

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    // handle rendering of second textured cube
    gl.useProgram(programTexture);

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(programTexture, "theta");
    posizLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(programTexture, "posiz");

    theta2[axis2] += rot2;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, flatten(theta2));
    gl.uniform4fv(posizLoc, posiz2);

    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );

//    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

For some reason, no cubes show up. Messing a bit with the code, I find that the javascript code breaks with alterations made following the

```
// get started on textured cube
```

comment line. The following javascript code is the same as the javascript code above save for code below the 'get started on textured cube' comment line:

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];
var texCoordsArray = [];

var texture; // second cube texture

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis1 = 0;
var axis2 = 0;

var rot1 = 1.0; // rate of rotation
var rot2 = 1.0;

var theta1 = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
var theta2 = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

// cube position along x, y, and z axis and size
var posiz1 = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ];
var posiz2 = [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ];

// used to send info back to html, I think
var thetaLoc;
var posLoc;

var firstCube = true;

// globals
var program;
var programTexture;
var iBuffer;
var cBuffer;
var vColor;
var vBuffer;
var vPosition;
var cBufferTexture;
var vColorTexture;
var vBufferTexture;
var vPositionTexture;
var tBuffer;
var vTexCoord;
var image;

    var vertices = [
        vec3( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 ),
        vec3(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 )
    ];

    var vertexColors = [
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
        vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
        vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
        vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
        vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
        vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
    ];

// indices of the 12 triangles that comprise the cube
var indices = [
    1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 6, 2,
    3, 0, 4, 4, 7, 3, 6, 5, 1, 1, 2, 6,
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1, 5
];

// texture coordinates
var texCoord = [
    vec2(0, 0),
    vec2(0, 1),
    vec2(1, 1),
    vec2(1, 0)
];

function configureTexture( image )
{
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(programTexture, "texture"), 0);
}

function quad(a, b, c, d)
{
     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]); 
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]); 

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]); 
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
     texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[3]);   
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    //event listeners for buttons
    document.getElementById( "switchButton" ).onclick = function ()
    {
        firstCube = !firstCube; // switch between cubes

        if (firstCube) document.getElementById("switchButton").value = "First";
        else document.getElementById("switchButton").value = "Second";
    };

    window.onkeydown = function(event)
    {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

        if (firstCube)
        {
            if (key == 'R') posiz1[0] += .1;
            else if (key == 'L') posiz1[0] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'U') posiz1[1] += .1;
            else if (key == 'D') posiz1[1] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'I') posiz1[2] += .1;
            else if (key == 'O') posiz1[2] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'G') posiz1[3] += .1;
            else if (key == 'S') posiz1[3] -= .1;

            if (event.shiftKey == 0 && (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z'))
                rot1 = -1.0;
            else if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z')
                rot1 = 1.0;

            if (key == 'X') axis1 = xAxis;
            if (key == 'Y') axis1 = yAxis;
            if (key == 'Z') axis1 = zAxis;
        }
        else
        {
            if (key == 'R') posiz2[0] += .1;
            else if (key == 'L') posiz2[0] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'U') posiz2[1] += .1;
            else if (key == 'D') posiz2[1] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'I') posiz2[2] += .1;
            else if (key == 'O') posiz2[2] -= .1;
            else if (key == 'G') posiz2[3] += .1;
            else if (key == 'S') posiz2[3] -= .1;

            if (event.shiftKey == 0 && (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z'))
                rot2 = -1.0;
            else if (key == 'X' || key == 'Y' || key == 'Z')
                rot2 = 1.0;

            if (key == 'X') axis2 = xAxis;
            if (key == 'Y') axis2 = yAxis;
            if (key == 'Z') axis2 = zAxis;
        }
    };

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    programTexture = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader-texture", "fragment-shader-texture" );

    gl.useProgram( program );
    colorCube();

    // array element buffer    
    iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // color array attribute buffer
    cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    // vertex array attribute buffer
    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    // get started on textured cube



    render();
}

function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // connect location to variable in html
    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");
    posizLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "posiz");

    // handle rendering of first cube
    theta1[axis1] += rot1;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta1);
    gl.uniform4fv(posizLoc, posiz1);

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    // handle rendering of second cube
    theta2[axis2] += rot2;

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta2);
    gl.uniform4fv(posizLoc, posiz2);

    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

This javascript file works fine when it comes to rendering two colored cubes but I don't know how to go about rendering a texture on the second cube.

I based my alterations on files texturedCube1.js and texturedCube1.html which can be retrieved here: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/07/.

I'm very much a novice which you can probably tell from my code and I'm not always certain what is going on under the hood. I'm going to continue tinkering with the javascript code but if anyone could help at least shed some light on why my cubes disappear or how to get a colored cube and textured cube at the same time, it would be very helpful.

Thank you so very much for your help and time in advance!

Comment: Create a fiddle or something, the chance of somebody investing the time of rebuilding your project with the referenced files and code are rather slim...

Comment: You're probably right... I just thought that perhaps some people who work in industry would be accustomed to working with even longer files of code. I was hoping there was something obvious that I wasn't able to see.

Comment: Well nobody is able to see *obvious* things when they're hidden in pages of unrelated source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try and run your code, but it looks like you have a problem here:

```
vBufferTexture = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBufferTexture );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

vPositionTexture = gl.getAttribLocation( programTexture, "vPosition" );
// here:
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPositionTexture, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPositionTexture );
```

`pointsArray` is an array of `vec3` but you are passing 4 as the number of components. Try:

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPositionTexture, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: Wow, it has done something! My cubes are no longer invisible! They're messed up but not invisible i.e. my javascript is no longer broken!

Comment: Thank you! This is a great help!

Comment: This was the break I needed. Thank you again!